# Android: How we can get the value from attribute from xml string

Tags: android, xml-parsing, opml

Can anybody tell me how we can parse the following Xml. I get the following xml as response of HttpGet method. I can be store this xml in the string form.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<opml version="1">

    <head>

    <status>200</status>

        </head>

    <body>

<outline type="text" text="General" guide_id="f1" is_default="true"/>

<outline type="text" text="Rock Stations" guide_id="f2"/>

<outline type="text" text="Rock Stations" guide_id="f3"/>

<outline type="text" text="Rock" guide_id="f4"/>

<outline type="text" text="Awdhesh" guide_id="f5"/>

    </body>

</opml>
```

I want to be parse the attribute of `outline`. And I also want to show the value of `text` in listview. Please provide me a sample code.

Thanks in Advance ...!!!

Comment: yea, But am new in android, so I haven't idea about parsing the attribute, But I can parse the value of status.

Comment: [Refer this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SAXParcer, see an example of sax parcer implementation:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-build-a-simple-sax-parser/

Please note method

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException
```

here you can check attributes and their values

```
if(localName.equals("outline"))
    String txtValue= attributes.getValue("text");
```