# Android: How we can parse opml String

Tags: android, parsing, opml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: How we can get the value from attribute from xml string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990767/android-how-we-can-get-the-value-from-attribute-from-xml-string)

I have the following string. I want to be parse the `attribute of outline`.

```
<opml version="1">
<head>
<status>200</status>
</head>
<body>
<outline type="text" text="General" guide_id="f1" is_default="true"/>
<outline type="text" text="Rock Stations" guide_id="f2"/>
<outline type="text" text="Rock Stations" guide_id="f3"/>
<outline type="text" text="Rock" guide_id="f4"/>
<outline type="text" text="Awdhesh" guide_id="f5"/>
</body>
</opml>
```

How I can parse attribute and take the value of `text` and `guide_id`.
Which parser I can use to do this?

Comment: This is Q/A site not code generation site, so dont ask for codes,rather ask for hints and guideline for the same,or you will get negative vote and also the question might get close, [Read More](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 0):

Use Dom Parser for that, Below is Link of Dom Parser Example.

[Dom Parsing](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-%E2%80%93-using-domparser)

Comment: This xml is not same as that xml which is provide by me. Can you provide any some guideline for parsing type, text and guide_id ...!!!

Comment: In Above Example link, the "category" is same as type, text and guide id, so use that type of parsing to parse type, text and guide id.